# Ruta de acceso a item en API de RapidAPI

Tags: api

Estoy intentando hacer pruebas con el plugin JetEngine para obtener datos de API's y mostrarlos en un sitio wordpress. Pero estoy estancado en la parte donde se configura el item path de la API:

[image: JetEngine Item Path]

La estructura de la API de prueba es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura de datos de la API]

El resultado que se muestra en JetEngine es que no se encontró. La autenticación está correcta, así como los query strings requeridos por la API:

[image: Query Strings requeridos]

Estos son los query strings requeridos:

limit=200&offset=0&postal_code='90004'&status='for_sale'

Me pueden indicar qué estoy haciendo mal? Probé con otra API que la estructura es simple y no requiere query strings y funciona bien, pero no con esta otra que estoy probando.

De antemano les agradezco mucho cualquier apoyo.

Saludos.